# PowerShell array/index/variable

Tags: powershell

The below code is checking in a dropdownbox, which item has been selected and then is searched in several arrays and as soon found, the loop is broken through break and I receive the correct information in "`$$($array.name)".

```
$search = $CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem.Split('-')[$($CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem.Split('-').Count - 1)].Trim() + '*'

$AllLocations = (Get-Variable -Include USPennsylvaniaAve, USSixthStreet, USRodeoDrive, USOneMicrosoftWay,`
                    USNorthTantauAvenue, USMarketStreet, USMainStreet, USEmilyDrive,`
                    USCalle8, USBroadway, US18thStreetNW, UKOxfordStreet, UKDowningStreet,`
                    UKBondStreet, FRRuedeRivoli, FRChampsElysees, CHBahnhofstrasse,`
                    CA17thAvenue) | ? {$_.value -is [array]}

foreach ($Array in $AllLocations) {
    if ($array.value -like $search) {
        break
    }
}
$test = "`$$($array.name)"
```

The issue is the variable `$test` does contain the correct array and I am interested, to work with the index (I hope I say that correctly).

For example, after the code ran and I enter `$test`, the result is for example `$USMarketStreet`, which is one of my arrays.

If I try to get the first index by typing `$test[0]` I do not get the expected content from the array, it gives me `$`.

If I enter `$test[0..4]` I get:

```
$
U
S
M
a
```

My intention was, to get the first key out of the array but instead of that, I am getting the first character out of the array name.

Is there a trick, how I can get to it? I also tried to play around with `$array` and `$array.value` but no success.

Comment: To put it bluntly: you reap what you sowed. DO NOT use dynamic variable names in your code. EVER. Throw that code away and start over by refactoring that myriad of individual variables into a more appropriate data structure, probably a hashtable.

Comment: To add a little more explanation about the result you're getting: `$test` does not contain a reference to the variable you want to use, but a string with the variable name. Using the index operator on that string gives you the characters from the specified indexes of that string.

Comment: Can't you just say `$test = $array`? Then `$test[0]` will grab the first array. If you want the name, then just type `$test[0].name`. If you want the value, just type `$test[0].value`. You can index further into the values by typing `$test[0].value[0]`, for example.

Comment: @AdminOfThings That would at best fix the symptom (if it works at all), but not the underlying problem of individually named variables. Which is very likely to raise more problems in the future.

Comment: @AdminOfThings the trick with the array.value[0] did the trick. I was not aware of this command, so thank you very much, on such way, I can avoid $test.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, well, I assume it is obvious that I have no clue about coding and I thought, I did not too bad and was happy, it was nearly working. Maybe the hashtable would be a better approach. Good thing is, this is only a theoretical idea and so won't end up in a productive system, so if the www is going down, you can't blame me ;)
Thank you very much for the help and the bluntly advise ;) I will try better in the future